# Why is my polymorphic type the class that my model inherits from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a model that inherits from a base other model:

```
class Instructor < User
```

I have another model with a polymorphic association:

```
class SiteResource < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :resource,  polymorphic: true
end
```

But when I make the new object, it has resource type User, not Instructor

```
irb(main):005:0> SiteResource.create(site: Site.first, resource: Instructor.first)
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | site_id | resource_id | resource_type | status | created_at              | updated_at              |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2  | 1       | 21          | User          | 1      | 2018-06-11 19:47:29 UTC | 2018-06-11 19:47:29 UTC |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Is this:

1. intended?
2. beneficial?
3. bad news?
4. configurable?

Comment: Well I guess that a model inherited from an ActiveRecord model is not itself an Activerecord model (well..). There is an explanation here on how it is stored http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html I have never used such design, what was your goal with such inherited model ?

Answer (score 1):

An example straight from the docs, literal copy pasted because I cannot explain it any better as they do

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, as: :attachable         # The :as option specifies the polymorphic interface to use.
end

@asset.attachable = @post
```

> Using polymorphic associations in combination with single table inheritance (STI) is a little tricky. In order for the associations to work as expected, ensure that you store the base model for the STI models in the type column of the polymorphic association. To continue with the asset example above, suppose there are guest posts and member posts that use the posts table for STI. In this case, there must be a type column in the posts table

Note: The attachable_type= method is being called when assigning an attachable. The **class_name of the attachable is passed as a String**.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  def attachable_type=(class_name)
     super(class_name.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # because we store "Post" in attachable_type now dependent: :destroy will work
  has_many :assets, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end

class GuestPost < Post
end

class MemberPost < Post
end
```

---

The official docs you need: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations